# JavaFX Controller class variables not binding to their FXML counterparts

Tags: java, binding, controller, javafx-2, fxml

When opening a new javafx window from a running javafx application I cannot bind the fxml variables to a local variable in the controller class.

Please note that for the running application I am able to bind to like-named variables without a problem, populating ComboBoxes in the running application at runtime. Any solutions are welcome.

Code that calls the new class (ServerConfigChooser)

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ServerConfigChooser.fxml"));
try{
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene( (Parent) loader.load()));
    stage.show();
} catch (IOException ex)...
```

Example of binding that works in the running application (code executed at runtime)

```
@FXML
public ComboBox cb_01_fxid;

private void initComboBox(){
    cb_01_fxid.getItems().add(0, "yes");
    cb_01_fxid.getItems().add(0, "no");
}
```

the fxid "cb_01_fxid" is identical in the controller class to the fxid of the ComboBox object in the .fxml file. This binds without a problem. Below is the code from the controller class for the new window (ServerConfigChooser).

```
1 @FXML
2 public ComboBox cb_02_fxid;
3
4 public void initComboBoxNewWindow(){
5     cb_02_fxid.addItems(0, "test item 1");
6 }
```

and the relevant fxml lines from the main application

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="728.9999000000025" prefWidth="735.0000999999975" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="model.Sample">
```

and the new window

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="283.0" prefWidth="445.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="model.ServerConfigChooser">
<ComboBox id="cb_02_fxid" layoutX="256.0" layoutY="84.0" onAction="#scc_cb_action">
```

the program throws a null pointer exception on line 5 (line numbers added for reference). Does anyone know why the second controller isn't binding to the second fxml object? Thanks in advance

Comment: Should work, assuming your fx:id and fx:controller are correctly set in ServerConfigChooser.fxml. Where is the method initComboBoxNewWindow() being called from?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have two different controller classes: one for the main application and one for your ServerConfigChooser?

Comment: Yes, there are two separate controller classes. initComboBoxNewWindow() is called from the initialize() method which is called automatically when the new window is created.

Comment: Then it should work (assuming `addItems(...)` is really `getItems().add(...)`). Double check your fx:id (make sure you didn't use id="..." by mistake...). Try a `System.out.println(cb_02)` in the `initialize(...)` method to see if it's null...?

Comment: please, provide your fxml

Comment: @Sergey -- edited to provide relevant FXML code. 
@ James_D -- I've printed the object in my debugging and it says it is null :/

Comment: you provided only first line of the FXML, what about ones there `cb_02` is declared?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev -- added the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ComboBox fxml part should have `fx:id` attribute set:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="cb_02"
```

This id should have EXACTLY same name as your variable in Controller class.

See tutorial for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

Comment: apologies mate, that was a code typo. The application fxid matches between the fxml variable and the controller variable, both being cb_02_fxid.

Comment: No, you have id="...". You need fx:id="...". (I mentioned this in the comments under the question too ;).)